# Clipboard paste to email

Tags: vba, outlook, clipboard

I am using some code to insert in an email the last clipboard print screen, but is there a way to choose the last 3 print screens? Or to choose multiple print screens to insert in the email? Thank you.

```
Sub clipboardcopy()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim oRng As Object


    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRINT SCREEN"

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 1
        oRng.Paste
        .Display
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't think this is possible.

The standard Windows clipboard contains only 1 item at a time.

The [Office clipboard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Office-Clipboard-028903c7-66ea-4eb0-b0a1-bacdb952e3a1) contains multiple items, but isn't accessible via VBA.

Comment: Then is there any way to insert when i press print screen ?

Comment: VBA cannot listen to the clipboard for events.  This limits your options.  You could write code that periodically checks the clipboard for changes.  But because VBA runs on one thread you might find this slows everything else down.  It would also be hard to avoid blocking any other code you wish to run.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more than one print screen, append it to the current mail rather than creating new mail.

The idea looks like this.

```
On Error resume next
Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentitem
on error goto 0

if curritem is nothing then

    Set OutMail = CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PRINT SCREEN"
        .Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        .Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        .Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 1
        oRng.Paste
        .Display
    End With

Else
    If curritem.class = olmail
        if curritem.subject = "PRINT SCREEN" then
            Set outMail = curritem

             ' code to append print screen to body of curritem

         End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but it does not work. I got until now only the one paste from clipboard but i will still look for multiple paste.